# Adding timeseries to cufflinks quantfig plot

Tags: plotly, candlestick-chart, cufflinks

Quantfig does 90% of what I am looking for but I want to add a custom time series to the main candlestick plot.  I am not as familiar with cufflinks as plotly but is there a similar function as fig.add_trace(go.Scatter()row=1, col=1) where a series can be added and a subplot can be assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Make list of dates out of your time series and apply qf.add_trendline(date1,date2) in cycle.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: I have been able to use "add_shapes" method to add a line into the candlestick, but it only allows for a single start and end point. @Art, are you suggesting putting this into a for loop to get the desired scatter? Is there an alternate method that is less "brute force"?